# Escaping % sign in subquery

Tags: mysql, escaping, subquery, special-characters

I have a query in mySQL that's meant to return search terms that are used on our site.  Yes, this is for a tag cloud, and yes, I know it's a mullet :)

We've got an admin page where administrators can view search terms and choose to exclude them from showing up in the cloud.  These words go into the "badWords" table.  We've gotten some terms like "foo%2525252525252520bar", and we're having trouble getting those excluded.

In pseudocode, the query to get the search terms for the cloud is:

```
SELECT * FROM `searchTerms` WHERE `word` NOT IN ( SELECT `word` FROM `badWords` )
```

This works fine, unless one of the terms returned from the subquery has a % in it.  Is there a way to escape the entire subquery?  I've tried doing a

```
replace( SELECT `word` FROM `badWords`, '%', '\%' )
```

... but that's apparently not syntactically correct.

I can do two queries if need be, but wondered if there's a way to get it done as is.

Thanks!

==============================

UPDATE: closing this for now, as I think the error lies elsewhere.  Will report back once I know for sure, but don't want folks wasting time answering the question here if it's not the correct question...

Upvoted both of the replies received so far.  Thanks, guys.

==============================

UPDATE 2: *sigh* Nevermind... can't close it :\

==============================

FINAL UPDATE: Well, looks like escaping the value isn't the problem.  The admin page passes the value in the URL before it's added to the badWords table.  In passing the value via the URL, it changes.  So what's added to badWords is actually "foo%25252525252520bar" (there's one less "25" sequence).  If I manually update the value in badWords and add back the missing "25" it works as expected.  So no need to replace or escape anything.  I just need to fix those URL values properly.

==============================

Comment: Can't you modify the search term immediately? Why that fuss about the `badwords`?

Comment: @glglgl - Modifying the search term immediately is the next thing I plan to look into.  For now, I want to fix up the existing functionality with the existing data.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the `%` is your problem here. I think that you're trying to use `REPLACE()` on the subquery itself (`SELECT ...`), and not on a column value (`word`). Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `searchTerms`
 WHERE `word` NOT IN (
   SELECT REPLACE(`word`, '%', '\%') AS word FROM `badWords`
 );
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very good with MySQL syntax, but SQL Server let's you do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `searchTerms` WHERE `word` NOT IN ( SELECT REPLACE(`word`, '%', '\%') FROM `badWords` )
```

**NOTE:**  Basically all I did was move your `REPLACE` over some =)  Hope this helps.